# using IPC under Service

Tags: android

Please can anyone tell me what is, and when would it be good to use "IPC" ?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPC stands for Inter-Process Communication. You need to use IPC if you have code in one process that needs to call methods on an object in another process. This way you can use in your application services provided by other applications.

You can find more info about IPC and AIDL in the Android Dev Guide
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html